# How can i run multiple management commands together in Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

How can i run below 3 commands together in a single window.

```html
.show databases | project DatabaseAccessMode, DatabaseAccessMode
.show tables | project DatabaseName, TableName;
.show function | project DatabaseName, TableName;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To execute `.show` commands together, you can use `Kusto.Cli.exe` tool. You can refer [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/tools/kusto-cli).

Download the  `Microsoft.Azure.Kusto.Tools` package from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Kusto.Tools/).
**Follow below steps to extract the package contents.**

1. Use any NuGet package explorer to extract the contents of downloaded package.
   I used 7-Zip tool to extract the package contents. Right clicked on downloaded package.
   [image]
2. Use `cd` command in command prompt and navigate to microsoft.azure.kusto.tools.11.2.2>tools>net6.0 folder.
3. After successful navigation, paste below command which is connecting to *help* cluster.
   `Kusto.Cli.exe "https://help.kusto.windows.net/Samples;Fed=true"`
   *https://help.kusto.windows.net/Samples;Fed=true* is considered as connection string.

**Steps to run all `.show` commands together**

1. Copy all `.show` commands into a txt file and save it with .txt extension. I used commands posted in question.
2. Commands in .txt file which I used to run through Kusto.cli.exe[image]
3. Then paste below command on command prompt. `Kusto.Cli.exe "https://help.kusto.windows.net/Samples;Fed=true" -script:"C:\Downloads\KQL_Cli.txt"`.

> You can change connection string which connects to your cluster and
> give file path and fileName of the file you saved in your system.

Execution result [image]